# Can you use EVD, SVD, PCA to solve least squares? (Intuitive Understanding)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, least-squares, svd, principal-component-analysis

I am trying to fully understand/demystify EVD, SVD and PCA. Am I right to assume all of these are tools/methods to solve least squares (not only but for CG)? If I am not wrong, even there are multiple types of least squares?

I am interested in computer graphics so my question is about finding the best fit plane, and oriented bounding box, etc.

I am looking for intuitive replies, as I am not academic.